# Can't install Couchbase sync gateway

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

Hey I'm trying to install Couchbase Sync Gateway in my iOS app but it doesn't work.
I am trying many but not sync or connect with Couchbase Server.

if you guys Know then tell me proper method or way to do that.

thanks

Comment: Can you provide some details of what you've tried, what exactly isn't working?

Comment: And just to be clear, the sync_gateway goes on an app server, not the iOS app. Couchbase Lite goes into the iOS app. Couchbase Lite connects to sync_gateway, which in turn connects to Couchbase DB Server.

Answer (score 1):

The Couchbase Sync Gateway is installed on your database server, where it can connect to a particular bucket of Couchbase. What you're looking to install on your iOS app is the CouchbaseLite library. You can easily install it via CocoaPods.
For reference, here is a GIT application with the Couchbase Lite already configured --> https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios
Try if you can connect to your sync gateway from there. That should give you a fair idea. Let me know if there are any other problems going forward.